# How to cause terraform to recreate the vnet peering with the Virtual Hub when the vnet CIDR is changed?

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-network

I want to change my vnet CIDR. The resulting terraform plan is simple:

```
  # module.bootstrap.module.vnets["australiaeast"].azurerm_subnet.subnet["aus"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
      ~ address_prefixes                               = [
          - "10.86.136.0/24",
          + "10.138.136.0/24",
        ]
        id                                             = "..."
        name                                           = "..."
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.bootstrap.module.vnets["australiaeast"].azurerm_virtual_network.vnet["vnet0"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
      ~ address_space           = [
          - "10.86.136.0/22",
          + "10.138.136.0/22",
        ]
      ~ dns_servers             = [
          - "10.86.10.36",
          - "10.86.10.37",
          + "10.138.10.36",
          + "10.138.10.37",
        ]
        id                      = "..."
        name                    = "..."
        # (5 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

However, this plan fails:

```
Error: creating/updating Virtual Network: (Name "..." / Resource Group "..."): network.VirtualNetworksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="AddressSpaceUpdateNotSupportedForVNetPeeredWithVHub" Message="Address space update not supported in virtual network ... as it is peered with managed vNet (vhub) .... Please delete hub virtual network connection, update the address space and then recreate hub virtual network connection. For more information please refer to https://aka.ms/VnetPeeringInfo" Details=[]
```

I would assume that this is the responsibility of the `azurerm` provider to recognize this situation and to plan to recreate the Virtual Hub connection, but apparently it does not work like this.

My terraform code is pretty straightforward:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_hub" "vhub" {
  provider            = azurerm.ss101
  name                = "..."
  resource_group_name = local.vhub_rg_name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_hub_connection" "spoke" {
  provider                  = azurerm.ss101
  name                      = "${var.app_vnet.name}-connection"
  virtual_hub_id            = data.azurerm_virtual_hub.vhub.id
  remote_virtual_network_id = var.app_vnet.id
  internet_security_enabled = true

  routing {
    associated_route_table_id = "..."
    propagated_route_table {
      route_table_ids = [
        for region in keys(local.transit_map) : "..."
      ]
      labels = ["default"]
    }
  }
}
```

My question - is it possible to change this terraform code so that when the VNET CIDR of `var.app_vnet` changes the vhub connection is recreated? It should be first dropped, then VNET CIDR updated and then the vhub connection should be created back.

Is it possible?

Comment: "responsibility of the azurerm provider to recognize this situation and to plan to recreate the Virtual Hub connection" a fair assumption, but I believe the config and plan of each provider resource is private to the struct, and therefore cannot be accessed by the other resources' methods.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - would you happen to know how we can code this logic ourselves using only terraform?